# How to resolve CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password?

Tags: java, security, veracode

I submitted my application EAR to Veracode Security scanning tool and got this flaw in the below piece of code  :

```
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/sql";  
private String userName = "xyz";  
private String password = "abc";
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); // At this line i am getting this flaw.
```

Someone please help me on  how to resolve CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password Flaw.

Comment: Have the password be passed as a command-line parameter; or read from a config file; or hard-code the encrypted password, then decrypt and connect.

Comment: @awashburn I can't imagine hard coding a password, encrypted or not, being a good idea. If someone figures the password out, you need to get a new version of the software to change the password. I'd go with your other option, a well protected, possibly encrypted, config file.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That's why it was the last option, a quick fix that may trick the auto-validator. It's obviously still not a good idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: I already stored my all passwords to connect to the database in properties file and then getting those values in my JAVA code.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting the hard-coded password flaw is because in line three of your snippet you are hard-coding your password in a variable.
This is because you are storing sensitive information (username and password) in the source code, which is a flaw because your can source can be decompiled.

One way to fix this flaw is to store the credentials in a strongly encrypted file, or apply strong one-way hashes to the credentials and store those hashes in a configuration file.

You can get more information here: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/259.html

Comment: I have stored my passwords in a properties file and then getting that value in my JAVA code.Could you please give me example of how to apply hashes to the credentials and storing those hashes in a configuration file?

Comment: Someone please help me on this by giving some examples to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -6):

**string Password = new Securestring("123").GetValue().**

```html
 class Securestring {
     private readonly string _password;

     public Securestring(string value) {
         _password = value;
     }

     public string GetValue() {
         return _password;
     }
 }
```