# Use of Hard-coded Password (CWE ID 259) C#

Tags: c#, passwords, hardcode

I'm using a piece of code related to the HttpClient in C# so passing some of the value as a parameter like:

```
var httpResponse = await this.httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/" + playListID + "/videos?access_token=" + this.GetVimeoAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret)));
```

Getting the issue  Use of Hard-coded Password (CWE ID 259) after the vera code scan.

So please guide how I handle the Hard-Coded Password issue.

Comment: no mention of password in the code you posted ? is it some other code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002369/how-to-resolve-cwe-259-use-of-hard-coded-password)